# text extraction in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a string as

```
My Id no is ++ 789456123456 <<.This is my 2nd no 987658974569
  new page
```

I want to extract `789456123456`, `987658974569` 
as comma-separated data. they are 12 digits in length

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and show what you have attempted.  You need to put in a bit of effort if you want someone to help you.   Take a look at the regex (regular expression) functions. the expression - "\d{12,}" should help. you can learn about regex at https://regex101.com/

Comment: Are you trying to extract all substrings of length exactly 12, made up of digits? Do you require that the extracted strings **not** be preceded or followed by any alphanumeric character (letter or digit)? Can there be any substrings of **more** than 12 digits in the input, and those should not be returned? And, what is the maximum number of substrings you may have to extract from a single string?

Comment: Please make your question more clear.

Comment: there can 5-10 substrings with 11-12  consecutive digits  and they wont be followed by alphabets or any other special chars. I want to extract all the 11-12 digits substring from a multiple line string. Count of digits in the substrings will be only 11 and 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
regexp_replace ('My Id no is ++ 789456123456 <<.This is my 2nd no 987658974569 new page' , 
`'.*([[:digit:]]{12}) .*([[:digit:]]{12}).*' , '\1 \2') 
from dual
```

Explanation:

`regexp_replace` --> Function can handle regular expression for replacement.

`'.*([[:digit:]]{12}) .*([[:digit:]]{12}).*'`--> this expression looks for `digit(0-0)` and `{12}` is number of time previous character should be repeated in this case 12.

`()` <-- are used for remembering patterns which can be used later

`\1 \2` <-- First and second group

This solution will not work if there is no spaces between 2 numbers

Edit: Updated code to handle line breaks

```
select  regexp_replace ( translate (col1 , chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), ' '), '.*([[:digit:]]{12}) .*([[:digit:]]{12}).*' , '\1,\2')  
from 
(
select 'We have received a consent for account no 540400005897 ,
    detail of which are given below: 895647895623 
    Detail: Please do not share this with anyone. Thank You.' as col1
from dual
)
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: Your solution is not working for the text-------> :       ' We have received a consent for account no 540400005897 ,detail of which are given below:
895647895623

Detail:   


Please do not share this with anyone.

Thank You.'

Comment: Text has multiple lines  like a paragraph

Comment: @ajeetVerma Check this solution https://rextester.com/NLJME31373